# Why won't my Page Field filter with the VisibleItemsList property?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, olap

**Page Field in OLAP Pivot Table no longer filters with pField.VisibleItemsList where pField is my Pivot Field variable**

I have a workbook that creates many copies of an adjusted Pivot Table as output reports. Some of the reports require a page field to be filtered on certain values, and others require it to be un-filtered. Previously, I used

```
pField.VisibleItemsList = Array("")
```

to un-filter the page field, and after populating the appropriate array I used

```
pField.VisibleItemsList = nameArray()
```

to filter the page field. Both of these lines now give me 1004 errors.

I was able to easily overcome the un-filter step by changing that line to

```
pField.ClearAllFilters
```

but I haven't found a similarly easy built-in solution for filtering the page field other than VisibleItemsList.

Here's the error message I'm getting on this code:

```
pField.VisibleItemsList = nameArray()
```

[1004 Error when Filtering the Page Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpFRN.jpg)